# How to generate the array of time durations

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to create an array of time durations in a day with 15 minute intervals with moment.js and ES6.

Example: `let time_duration= ["15 Min", "30 Min",..., "1 hr 15 min", "1 hr 30 min"]`

Comment: To create a function that returns the veriable `time_duration`?

Comment: yes , create function that return the variable

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it supposed to work:

```js
  generateTimeDurations(minutesGap: number, length: number): string[] {
    const result = Array(length).fill(null);
    let acc = 0;
    return result.map(_ => {
      acc += minutesGap;
      if (acc >= 60) {
        return `${Math.floor(acc / 60)} hr ${acc % 60} min`;
      } else {
        return `${acc} min`;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need static time levels like "15 Min", "30 Min" and so on you could try to do it in plain JS with `Array#fill` and `Array#map`.

```js
const hours = 24;
const minutes = 24 * 60;

function minsToHM(totalMins) {
  let padZero = value => String(value).padStart(2, "0");

  totalMins = Number(totalMins);
  const h = Math.floor(totalMins / 60);
  const m = Math.floor(totalMins % 60);

  const hDisplay = h > 0 ? padZero(h) + (h == 1 ? " Hour" : " Hours") : "";
  const mDisplay = m > 0 ? padZero(m) + (m == 1 ? " Min" : " Mins") : "";
  return `${hDisplay}${h > 0 && m > 0 ? ", ": ""}${mDisplay}`;
}

function splitHours(hours, difference) {
  const mins = hours * 60;
  return Array(Math.floor(mins / difference))
    .fill(1)
    .map((_, idx) => (idx+1) * difference)
}

const output = splitHours(1.5, 15).map(i => minsToHM(i))
console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0px }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.clear();

function digitToMinute(digit) {
  return digit * 60 / 100;
}

function minutesToDigit(minute) {
  return minute * 100 / 60;
}

function digitsToHourAndMinutes(digit) {
  return [Math.floor(digit / 60), digitToMinute(getFraction(digit / 60))];
}

function getFraction(f) {
  return Math.ceil(((f < 1.0) ? f : (f % Math.floor(f))) * 100)
}

function getIntervals(max) {
  var intervals = [];
  var span = 15;
  var i = 0;
  while (i <= max) {

    if (i > 0) {
      let [hour, minute] = digitsToHourAndMinutes((i));
      let string = [];
      if (hour > 0) {
        string.push(hour + ' hour');
      }
      if (minute > 0) {
        string.push(minute + ' minutes');
      }

      intervals.push(string.join(' '));
    }

    i = i + span;
  }
  return intervals;
}

console.log(getIntervals(60 * 5));
```